# graph drawing peculiarities

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the following graph: vertices are integers between $1$ and $n,$ where $a$ is connected to $b$ if $a$ divides $b.$ This is easily constructed in *Mathematica* thus:

```
divGraph[n_] := 
 With[{pairs = Subsets[Range[n], {2}]}, 
  With[{divis = Select[pairs, Mod[#[[2]], #[[1]]] == 0 &]}, 
   Graph[Apply[Rule, #] & /@ divis, VertexLabels -> "Name"]]]
```

OK, let's now look at `divGraph[8]`:

[image: divGraph[8]]

You will notice that you cannot see the edge connecting $1$ to every other vertex, though we all know there should be such an edge. Is this a bug? Can it be worked around?

PS: If you are curious about why one might want to look at such a thing, see [this MO question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280985/divisibility-independence)

Comment: Which edge is missing (besides 1$\to$1)?

Comment: Yeah.... What's the problem?

Comment: an alternative way to define `divGraph` : `divGraph[n_] := RelationGraph[UnsameQ @ ## && Divisible[#2, #]&, Range @ n]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what edges you're having trouble seeing.

To highlight the edges connecting 1 to everyone else you can use `Highlight`.

```
divGraph[8]~ HighlightGraph ~ (1 -> # & /@ Range[2, 8])
```

[image]

Maybe you'll like the layout better of:

```
Graph[divGraph[8], GraphLayout -> "RadialDrawing"] // 
 HighlightGraph[#, 1 -> # & /@ Range[2, 8]] &
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps temporary blindness, but on the other hand, the radial drawing looks way better, so I am  glad I asked!